# Navigate into layer using arrow key

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build some functionality (using JQuery) into a custom built auto complete layer. I want the user to be able to arrow down into the layer and then back up again into the input box (which triggered the layer in the first place). The code below will show you that you can actually arrow/up and down the list and select an item but I have 3 issues:

1) When you arrow down the window also scrolls down with it even though I added prevent default

2) When you get to the end of the list it loops back round. It needs to stop at the end

3) When you go back to the first element in the list - then the next UP action - should take you back into the input box.

```js
// Arrow up and down controls
window.displayBoxIndex = -1;

jQuery("#searchForm").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Navigate(1);
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Navigate(-1);
  }
});

var Navigate = function(diff) {
  displayBoxIndex += diff;
  var oBoxCollection = jQuery(".ac-list");
  if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
    displayBoxIndex = 0;
  if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
    displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
  var cssClass = "selected";
  oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass).children('a').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchForm">
  <textarea accesskey="4" placeholder="Enter search terms..." id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm"></textarea>
  <div id="autoComplete">
    <ul>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">etc...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also add the jquery you are using?

Comment: Its a bit tricky to include as it is embedded in some JAVA but essentially onkeypress it fires an event to show the layer and populate the list with results via ajax.

Comment: So when it's open use key event also and check event object to see which key was pressed

Comment: Yes that is the part I am struggling with ... how to navigate from the input box down/up the list and back into the input box.

Comment: I think to focus out of the search box on arrow keys is a bad UX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround to get your goal achieved :

**Q1 :** *"When you arrow down the window also scrolls down with it even though I added prevent default"*

**A :** a long answer that can be applied (parts of it) to the other question. That's the logic behavior to occur when pressing arrow keys and you have attached a `keyup` listener but that event **can't be undone** as the key is already pressed :

- `keyup` can catch arrow keys but **can't** be undone `==>` not an option.
- `keypress` can be undone but **can't** catch arrow keys `==>` not an option.
- `keydown` **can** catch arrow keys and **can** be undone `==>` what we need, perfect.

  So `keydown` is the qualified event but so let's assume you changed the events to `keydown` :
- imagine you have focused the `textarea#searchTerm` and pressed the down arrow to start navigating in the autocomplete box, the event won't trigger (due to `preventDefault` call).
- we can't even start navigating with arrow keys after calling `preventDefault`.

A solution is to think a bit wisely :

- attach a `keydown` handler to the `window` that checks if the current focused element in the page (`$(document.activeElement)`) is either the `form#searchForm` or one of its children (like the autocomplete items) and the key that being pressed is the up/down arrow then we prevent that event thus no scrolling down when scrolling into the autocomplete list.
- attach a `keydown` handler to the `form#searchForm` that sees if the key pressed isn't up/down arrow then stop the event propagation to prevent getting bubbled to the `window` thus allowing us to write and navigate in the autocomplete list (remember we have `preventDefault` called in the handler for the `window` that can prevent us from writing).
- a final handler for `keydown` attached to `textarea#searchTerm` (even though an `input[type="text"]` seems to be more suitable preventing line breaks, that may appear in a `textarea`, at least) that has a simple and important task which is while focusing (writing in) the field and the up arrow gets pressed we don't allow the autocomplete list last item to be selected.

> the ordering when adding these handlers is very important : first attch `form#searchForm` handler, `textarea#searchTerm`'s and then the handler for the `window`.

**Q2 :** *"When you get to the end of the list it loops back round. It needs to stop at the end"*

**A :** in the `Navigate` function we see if the `displayBoxIndex` variable (that tracks which item to be selected) has reached the last item and the down arrow was pressed then we just `return` to quit the function.

**Q3 :** *"When you go back to the first element in the list - then the next UP action - should take you back into the input box"*

**A :** also in the `Navigate` function we check if `displayBoxIndex` variable is at the first item and the up arrow was pressed then we trigger `focus` for the text field, remove the `selected` class from the autocomplete items, reset `displayBoxIndex` variable to `-1` (ensuring we start from the first item when the down arrow gets pressed while typing) and finally `return` to halt the function.

> this line `displayBoxIndex += diff` must appear **after** the above two condition in order to get correct calculation for which element we're selecting and the next one to be selected.

So, here's a demo to illustrate, it contains a wealth of helpful comments that may assist you while reading, also some covers some changes made into the code that I didn't cover above :

```js
const form = $('#searchForm'),
  searchTerm = $('#searchTerm'),
  autoc = $('#autoComplete'),
  jqWin = jQuery(window),
  oBoxCollection = jQuery('.ac-list'),
  cssClass = 'selected',
  Navigate = diff => {
    /** focus the text field when in the first item and the up arrow was pressed **/
    if (displayBoxIndex === 0 && diff === -1) {
      searchTerm.trigger('focus');
      oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass);
      displayBoxIndex = -1;
      return;
    }
    /** prevent looping back when reached the last item in the autocomplete box **/
    if (displayBoxIndex === oBoxCollection.length - 1 && diff == 1) return;

    /** make the navigation **/
    displayBoxIndex += diff;
    oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass)
      .eq(displayBoxIndex)
      .addClass(cssClass)
      .children('a')
      .focus();
  };

let displayBoxIndex = -1;

/** attaching events with respect of ordering **/

/** 1: keydown listener on the form **/
form.on('keydown', e => {
  const upOrDown = [38, 40].indexOf(e.which) != -1;
  /** is it the up/down key  **/
  !upOrDown && (e.stopPropagation());
  /** if no (another key) just stop the event propagation so the one attached to the window won't be fired **/
  upOrDown && (Navigate(e.which == 40 ? 1 : -1));
  /** if yes we call we call Navigate (if we gets here to the ternary operator the e.which is either 40 or 38) **/
  e.which == 27 && (autoc.slideUp(400, () => {
    searchTerm.blur();
    displayBoxIndex = -1;
    oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass);
  }));
});

/** 2: keydown listener on the text field **/

/** prevent going to the list box bottom when pressing up arrow **/
searchTerm.on({
  keydown: e => {
    e.which == 38 && (e.stopPropagation());
  },
  focus: e => {
    /** show the autocomplete box if is hidden **/
    autoc.is(':hidden') && (autoc.slideDown(400));
    displayBoxIndex = -1;
  } /** reset navigation position (resets to the first item in the autocomplete box) when the text field is focus **/
});

/** 3: keydown listener on the window **/
jqWin.on('keydown', e => {
  const focus = $(document.activeElement);
  /** get the current focused element in the page **/
  [38, 40].indexOf(e.which) != -1 && (focus.is('#searchForm') ||
    form.has(focus).length) && (e.preventDefault());
  /** prevent scroll when navigating in the autocomplete box (the scrolling you asked about in your first question) **/
});
```

```css
/** basic styling to appear like a real autocomplete box. Doesn't affect the main functionality required **/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.wrapper textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  border: 2px solid #181818;
  resize: none;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}

.wrapper textarea:focus {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper #autoComplete {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px -8px rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
}

.wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #181818;
}

.wrapper ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover,
.selected {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- added a wrapper div in the form just to simplify the styling it has nothing related to the functionality -->
<form id="searchForm">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <textarea placeholder="Enter search terms..." id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm"></textarea>
    <div id="autoComplete">
      <ul>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 1</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 2</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 3</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 4</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 5</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 6</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 7</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 8</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 9</a></li>
        <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">autocomplete item 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope I managed to provide some help.

Comment: This was perfect the only other thing I need is to close the autocomplete layer when the escape key is pressed. I have this functionality but when you arrow in it doesnt work?

     jQuery(document).on( 'keydown', function (e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
     jQuery("#autoCompleteDeluxe").hide();
    }
});

Comment: i'll make these changes and update the answer ASAP.

Comment: @j00m updated, check the snippet please and press `ESC` key when focusing the `textarea`.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt seem to make any difference you still cant ESC out of the layer when you have arrowed in

Comment: @j00m you said when typing and pressing `ESC` close the autocomplete box. Anyway, I'll update the snippet so when pressing `ESC` even while navigating in the autocomplete box it should close that autocomplete box.

Comment: @j00m I made the change take a look.

Comment: Thanks the only other issue is IE 11 error:

syntax error 

Navigate = diff => {

Comment: @j00m for sure I know that IE won't support some syntax in the code above, maybe IE doesn't support arrow functions as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Focusing**

> [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection#Focused_Elements): Only one element per window has the focus at a time.

So, the search box and any list element cant be focused at a time. But some autocomplete plugins like [`select2`](https://select2.org/dropdown) having a solution for this. They just toggle a class to set an active list element.

Here the class `active` used to highlight the selected list element.

**Navigating**

Navigation becomes tricky when the search box has a value. Here the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) along with the `nextAll()` / `prevAll()` helps to select first visible list element

**Searching and Highlighting**

Searching loops through the list and toggle the visibility of the list. Highlighting uses the regex replace and [`mark`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) tag.

**Complete working demo with search**

```js
$('#searchTerm').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var $allLinks = $('#autoComplete .ac-list');
  var $visibleLinks = $allLinks.filter(':visible');
  var $activeLink = $visibleLinks.filter('.active');
  console.log(e.originalEvent.code)

  if (e.which === 40) { // ArrowDown
    $allLinks.removeClass('active');
    $activeLink = $activeLink.nextAll(':visible:first').addClass('active');
    if ($activeLink.length === 0) {
      $activeLink = $visibleLinks.first().addClass('active'); // to beginning of list
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.which === 38) { // ArrowUp
    $allLinks.removeClass('active');
    $activeLink = $activeLink.prevAll(':visible:first').addClass('active');
    if ($activeLink.length === 0) {
      $activeLink = $visibleLinks.last().addClass('active'); // to end of list
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.which === 13) { // Enter
    $activeLink.trigger('click');
  }

  if ($activeLink.get(0)) {
    $activeLink.get(0).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'instant',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }
});

$('#searchTerm').on('keyup', function() {
  var value = this.value.replace(/[\W_]+/g, " ").trim();
  if (this.prevValue === value) return;
  this.prevValue = value;
  $('.ac-list').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().search(new RegExp(value, "i")) > -1) {
      $this.show()
      .find('a').html(this.innerText.replace(new RegExp(value + '(?!([^<]+)?<)', "gi"), '<mark>$&</mark>')); // highloghts the searched text
    } else {
      $this.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #5897fb;
}


/* theming */

#searchForm {
  width: 200px;
}

#searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
}

#autoComplete {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#autoComplete ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#autoComplete ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#autoComplete ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#autoComplete ul li.active a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="searchForm">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Enter search terms..." id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm">
  <div id="autoComplete">
    <ul>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Afghanistan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Åland Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Albania</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Algeria</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">American Samoa</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">AndorrA</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Angola</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Anguilla</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Antarctica</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Antigua and Barbuda</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Armenia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Aruba</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Azerbaijan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bahamas</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bahrain</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bangladesh</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Barbados</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Belarus</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Belgium</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Belize</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Benin</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bermuda</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bhutan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bolivia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Botswana</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bouvet Island</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">British Indian Ocean Territory</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Brunei Darussalam</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Bulgaria</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Burkina Faso</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Burundi</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cambodia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cameroon</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cape Verde</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cayman Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Central African Republic</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Chad</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">China</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Christmas Island</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Colombia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Comoros</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Congo</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cook Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Costa Rica</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cote D'Ivoire</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Croatia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cuba</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Cyprus</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Czech Republic</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Denmark</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Djibouti</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Dominica</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Dominican Republic</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Ecuador</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">El Salvador</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Equatorial Guinea</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Eritrea</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Estonia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Ethiopia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Faroe Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Fiji</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">France</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">French Guiana</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">French Polynesia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">French Southern Territories</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Gabon</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Gambia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Georgia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Ghana</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Gibraltar</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Greece</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Greenland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Grenada</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guadeloupe</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guam</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guatemala</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guernsey</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guinea</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guinea-Bissau</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Guyana</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Haiti</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Holy See (Vatican City State)</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Honduras</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Hong Kong</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Hungary</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Iceland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">India</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Indonesia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Iran, Islamic Republic Of</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Iraq</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Ireland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Isle of Man</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Israel</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Jamaica</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Jersey</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Jordan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Kazakhstan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Kenya</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Kiribati</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Korea, Republic of</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Kuwait</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Kyrgyzstan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Lao People'S Democratic Republic</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Latvia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Lebanon</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Lesotho</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Liberia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Liechtenstein</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Lithuania</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Luxembourg</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Macao</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Madagascar</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Malawi</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Malaysia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Maldives</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mali</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Malta</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Marshall Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Martinique</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mauritania</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mauritius</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mayotte</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Micronesia, Federated States of</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Moldova, Republic of</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Monaco</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mongolia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Montserrat</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Morocco</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Mozambique</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Myanmar</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Namibia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Nauru</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Netherlands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Netherlands Antilles</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">New Caledonia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">New Zealand</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Nicaragua</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Niger</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Nigeria</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Niue</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Norfolk Island</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Northern Mariana Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Oman</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Pakistan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Palau</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Panama</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Papua New Guinea</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Paraguay</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Peru</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Philippines</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Pitcairn</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Portugal</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Puerto Rico</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Qatar</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Reunion</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Romania</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Russian Federation</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">RWANDA</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Saint Helena</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Saint Kitts and Nevis</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Saint Lucia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Samoa</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">San Marino</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Sao Tome and Principe</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Saudi Arabia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Senegal</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Serbia and Montenegro</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Seychelles</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Sierra Leone</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Slovakia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Slovenia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Solomon Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Somalia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Sri Lanka</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Sudan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Suriname</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Swaziland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Sweden</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Switzerland</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Syrian Arab Republic</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Taiwan, Province of China</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Tajikistan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Tanzania, United Republic of</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Timor-Leste</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Togo</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Tokelau</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Tonga</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Trinidad and Tobago</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Tunisia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Turkey</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Turkmenistan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Turks and Caicos Islands</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Tuvalu</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Uganda</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Ukraine</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">United Arab Emirates</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">United States</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Uzbekistan</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Vanuatu</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Venezuela</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Viet Nam</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Virgin Islands, British</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Virgin Islands, U.S.</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Wallis and Futuna</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Western Sahara</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Yemen</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Zambia</a></li>
      <li class="ac-list"><a href="#">Zimbabwe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```